# I once read that static classes are very difficult and even impossible to debug. Is this true and why?

Tags: language-agnostic, static, static-classes

I once read that static classes are very difficult and even impossible to debug. Is this true and why?

If an example would help, here is a `PHP` class I use to access a database (I don't think this is a PHP-specific question, though):

```
<?php

class DB
{
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() { }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!self::$instance)
        {
            self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function getPreparedStatement($query)
    {
        $db = self::getInstance();
        return $db->prepare($query);
    }

    public static function query($query)
    {
        $stmt = self::getPreparedStatement($query);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    public static function getResult($query)
    {
        $stmt = self::getPreparedStatement($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }

    public static function getSingleRow($query)
    {
        $stmt = self::getPreparedStatement($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }

    public static function getMultipleRows($query)
    {
        $stmt = self::getPreparedStatement($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Hope you are prepared for a war... there is a lot of hate toward static classes/methods, and it gets even worse when you bring up singletons...

Comment: That's okay :-) I am curious about the subject and look forward to the answers that people provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your static class has methods and no data, it's just a namespace.  No problem there.  But if you have static *data*, you run into the same problems as global variables: you can no longer understand the behavior of the system from looking at local information.  Particularly in a multi-threaded environment, you could be in for unexpected behavior and difficult debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that what you read was related to **testing** those classes.

For a good indepth explanation on this and much more, I'd suggest you read [Misco's](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/) blog. I have found them to be a valuable source of information.

> The basic issue with static methods is
>   they are procedural code. I have no
>   idea how to unit-test procedural code.
>   Unit-testing assumes that I can
>   instantiate a piece of my application
>   in isolation. During the instantiation
>   I wire the dependencies with
>   mocks/friendlies which replace the
>   real dependencies. With procedural
>   programing there is nothing to “wire”
>   since there are no objects, the code
>   and data are separate.

Comment: I think its a two part issue dealing with mocking static classes or mocking classes that have static methods.  Mainly because you cant interface them.